# getting this error "expected primary-expression before '.' token" new to c++

Tags: c++

I don't get what the problem is here but I'm getting this error:

> [Error] expected primary-expression before '.' token:

Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct  employee
{
  char  emp_name[10];
  int   emp_no;
  int   duty[3];
  int   salary[3];
};

int  main()
{
  cout << "enter employee naem";
  cin >> employee.emp_name;
  cout << "enter employee number";
  cin >> employee.emp_no;
  cout << "enter employee salary";
  cin >> employee.emp_salary;
  cout << "enter employee duty assigned";
  cin >> employee.emp_duty;
  cout << "employee name = " << employee.emp_name << endl;
  cout << "employee number = " << employee.emp_no << endl;
  cout << "employee duty-assigned" << employee.duty << endl;
  cout << "employee salary per duty" << employee.emp_salary << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define the `employee` ?

Comment: You have an `employee` type, but no `employee` object. You should define an object of type `employee`

Comment: `employee` is a type. You need in instance. Rename `struct employee` to `struct Employee` and add `Employee employee;` as the first line of main.

Comment: Also you need to `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 3):

In your code `employee` is a class not an object. You never create an instance of that type. I suggest you to use a naming convention that distinguishes types from objects. For example:

```
using namespace std;

struct  Employee {
    std::string name;
    int emp_no;
    int duty[3];
    int salary[3];
};
int main()
{
    Employee employee;
    // ....
}
```

Comment: `emp_salary` is also not a member of their struct.